# Least system tasking sorting algorithm for ~100-150 objects by a single field?

Tags: java, sorting

I will have ~100-150 person objects.  There will be two fields: `int idNumber` and `string name` that I would like to sort those objects by (one method will sort by `name`, and an overloaded version by `idNumber`).  Sorting would be done only by one of those fields at a time, so no other field would be compared.  What would be the most efficient sorting algorithm?

By "efficient" I mean this: I'm looking for something that's least tasking on the system.  Since it's only 100-150 objects, speed is not of a great concern; however, this program is going to be ran on rather resource-deprived systems, so I want something that requires the least resources.

P.S. This is in Java, but I don't think that matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have the objects in memory. If that's the case, for just 100-150 objects I don't think there's a significant difference in any of the built in sorting algorithms you can use in Java.

You can just use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and provide a different Comparator for each case.

Comment: Yes, the objects will be in memory.  If there's no measurable difference between the sorting algorithms with such a small number of objects, I guess it's best to for the simplest.  The one you mentioned looks pretty simple.